# Is there a nesting limit for subqueries in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am constructing the query string in code and the easiest way I see to add new parameters is to add subqueries something like this:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM table";
query = "SELECT * FROM (" + query 
         + MessageFormat.format(" ) as subquery where x = {0}", y);
query += ";";
```

So I might have quite a lot of such subqueries at the end and I wonder if there is a limit I might hit.

Comment: I suspect not; views are essentially just sub-queries so the nested depth could be much deeper than appears.  It should be quite easy to test though.  Just recurse a trivial example 1000 times deeper than you ever expect to go...

Comment: In theory: barely. In practice: it depends. BTW: your example is too trivial, the optimiser probably will unfold it. :: `select * FROM( select * FROM(select * from t) a ) b;` can be reduced to a plain `select * from t;`

Answer (score 1):

Not really - You should go ahead and try it. However, I believe there could be a performance impact though. To the extent possible use joins and such direct methods.

Answer (score 0):

I use nested subqueries extensively myself, even for a similar use-case, and in PostgreSQL I haven't reached any kind of limit. For example in MySQL the situation is different, as you can only reference fields in a first-level subquery; any deeper and you're out of luck.